# Testing my layout on all devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I want to test my layout on all devices, since my layout is not seen properly in small devices.

Is there any website or tools which can help me?

please suggest.

Below is xml layout for main activity. it works in big screen mobile but not small screen.

Layout contains gridview + fab button + adview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="Overdraw">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/hideMenu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBox"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submittedstatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/statusdesc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/status" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submittedImg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/ImageContent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/image" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/submittedPost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/postdesc"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/post" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sharewhite" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addpersonality"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/personality"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/personality" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addfort"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/fort"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/fort" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addwar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/war"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            ads:srcCompat="@drawable/war" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="160dp">


    </GridView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="LARGE_BANNER"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>



    </LinearLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add some details of layout

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: i have unpdated post with xml code.. Pleas advice

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio's Layout Editor you can simulate different screen sizes and see how the layout appears in each screen size

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor.html#change-appearance

[image]

Comment: Thanks shmuel, will definitely try this

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your question please mark this as the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to check your layout for different phones is to use the **Device in Editor** setting and select which phone you want to try on. You reach this setting by selecting the xml file you want to check and then press the design tab in the bottom left corner. The setting is then visible above the layout in the designer view. You may also add other phones that are not visible in the list.

[image: Device in Editor]

Answer (score 0):

@cool trick 
There is preview tab in the android studio to your right-top while you edit layout.

It is really cool menu tab you can configure devices as per your need.

Cheers!!

And suppose you want to create a different attribute for same layout for the mob and large devices then you can have same name layout. just create one more folder "layout-large".